# Scope defined query doesn't work but standalone query is ok

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rails-activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
  scope :my_scope, -> { where(user_id: 2) }
end
```

Why does `category.posts.my_scope` return all posts?

The following two statements correctly returns only posts with user_id 2:

```
category.posts.where(user_id: 2)
Post.my_scope
```

Can I not use scope on chained objects?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks good from here.

> Why does category.posts.my_scope return all posts?

Is it possible in your example that *all* the posts for this specific category belong to the user with `id: 2`?

An easy way to tell is to do this: `category.posts.my_scope.to_sql` to see if it works the way you intend it to. You could compare it to `Post.my_scope.to_sql`

Comment: I ran the two queries with `to_sql` and they are identical except for the `AND`. So it has to be something funky going on in my code elsewhere. (No, most posts have different user_id.)

Comment: Updated my answer.